# Tags [prepared-statement] and [prepare] should be synonymous

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I just reviewed a question which already had the [prepare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prepare) tag (237 questions) and one of the changes was to add the [prepared-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prepared-statement) (4,239 questions).  The tag wikis for the two tags make it clear that they're discussing the same feature — prepared statements in SQL.

I've created a synonym suggestion under [prepared-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prepared-statement) so that [prepare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prepare) should become a synonym for [prepared-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prepared-statement).

This is mostly a request for those who are vaguely interested and who have enough reputation to up-vote the suggested synonym at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prepared-statement/synonyms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes sense to me, I went ahead and did this.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes it easy.